# Can’t send a file response for the storage folder in Laravel 5.2 on Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

What I wanted to do, is to protect my private files, so that only their owners could access them. I changed my public disk to storage folder:

```
'orders' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path('files/orders'),
],
```

And created a routed controller to be able to make files private (I intentionally excluded this logic from the example):

```
Route::get('files/{slug}', [
    'as'   => 'get.file',
    'uses' => 'FileController@getFile',
]);

class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function getFile($slug)
    {
        // I use spatie/laravel-medialibrary
        // to manage file uploads.
        $media = Media::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        return response()->file($media->getPath());
    }
}
```

The `getPath()` is a `spatie/laravel-medialibrary` method that returns the correct path to the file: `/home/vagrant/code/project/storage/files/orders/2/b414a7416571145ea9dcf9bda9a845a2.jpg`. It clearly finds the file, because I can use `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File()` to get files’ data like their mime type or size (and also don’t get a 404 error as a response); when I follow, say, `http://localhost:3000/files/2RmYR3` route I get this blank 200 response—looks like so:

[image]

One person tested pretty much the same code on his end, and it worked, but he was on Valet, so it might be a Homestead issue. He also suggested it might be an issue with headers, and I tried sending different headers (content-type/length, for instance), but nothing helped, so please see what I’m receiving without specifying any headers for the response:

[image]

I also tried `vagrant destroy`, just in case, but the issue stayed. In any case, thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try `response()->download()`?

Comment: @user2094178 I did, it downloads a file, its size is correct, but it’s broken, and can’t be viewed or opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved itself. I started stripping pieces from the application to understand which part of the code messes with responses, at first I thought it was my view composer, but no; I did a fresh separate Laravel installation, and copied `config/app.php` from the fresh installation to my project, then just updated lists of providers and aliases that I had before, and that did it.

My `app.php` lacked `'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),` line that was added at some point to Laravel after I started the project, and maybe that’s why responses didn’t work properly, but I doubt it.